# Create ui file for Qt Designer from .cpp and .h

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I have project that have UI part written in Qt. It have form files and I clearly see that they were generated with Qt Designer, but .ui file is absent. Is it possible to generate .ui file from that .cpp and .h files to have possibility modify this form in Qt Designer?

Comment: why converting c++ code into xml, store it in the .ui file and let the user interface compiler recreate c++ code out of it?
ok, you have the 'clicky' thing when you want to change it, but i find it more flexible to code the ui instead of clicking it together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is absolutely impossible. Not enough information in .cpp and .h files to generate .ui files.

Comment: Perhaps Borrimoro's best bet is to run the program and Qt Designer at the same time, and then hand-create a new .ui file in Designer that matches the layout seen in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at QFormBuilder::save()

"save() handles saving of widget details in UI format to arbitrary QIODevices."